# Does Testcafe retry assertions with Selector.count and Selector.exists?

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

In testcafe documentation I found that assertions with `count` and `exists`  ["execute immediately regardless of the selector timeout"](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402829/guides/basic-guides/select-page-elements#selector-timeout). However in  [wait-mechanism-for-assertions](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402827/guides/concepts/built-in-wait-mechanisms#wait-mechanism-for-assertions) paragraph documentation states that "TestCafe keeps recalculating the actual value until it matches the expected value or the assertion timeout passes".

So, do assertions with `exists` execute immediately or use the default "assertion timeout" (3000ms)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between [Selector Timeout](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402638/reference/configuration-file#selectortimeout) and [Asseertion Timeout](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402638/reference/configuration-file#assertiontimeout).

Selector Timeout specifies the time (in milliseconds) within which selectors attempt to return a node.
Assertion Timeout specifies the amount of time (in milliseconds) TestCafe attempts to successfully execute an assertion.

For the `exists` and `count` property, the Selector Timeout will be ignored:

```
// NOTE: there is no timeout here
console.log(await Selector('non-existing-element').count)
```

However, the Assertion Timeout will be applied:

```
// NOTE: there is a timeout
await t.expect(Selector('non-existing-element').count).eql(100)
```